# CMD DOS Running DIR command in order to find a specific file extension

Tags: cmd, dos

I would like to list only XML files from the folder "C:\Test\Path" and save the results to a text file.

However, the following command lists all files from the folder and not only the XML files:

cmd /c dir "C:\Test\Path" /s /b *.xml> c:\Test\RunDIROnXMLFolder11.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the proper syntax is:

```
cmd /c dir /s /b "C:\Test\Path\*.xml" > c:\Test\RunDIROnXMLFolder11.txt
```

(`/s` and `/b` may be before or after the filespecification, but this should be

```
<drive>:\<path>\<filespec>
```

Comment: Hmm - the point is that the original instruction asked for two different specifications, `"C:\Test\Path"` and `*.xml`, so `cmd` produced a directory listing of filenames matching either `"C:\Test\Path"` **or** `*.xml` Useful in some circumstances, but not in this.

Comment: @Magoo: yes, that's what his code does. But what he wants: "list only XML files from the folder". To take it word by word, even the `/s` is too much.

Comment: The "/b" needs to be capitalized ("/B") as t_m pointed it out. Thanks both of you guys

Comment: @user3566591 just curious: why /b "needs to be capitalized"? As far as I know, `dir`'s parameters are not case sensitive.

Comment: @Stephan: you are right, "/b" does not need to be capitalized actually.

Answer (score 0):

Try ..

```
cmd /c dir /s /B "C:\Test\Path\*.xml" > c:\Test\RunDIROnXMLFolder11.txt
```